# z-index conundrum - if A is child of B and C is displayed over B, can A be displayed over C?

Tags: css

I had some trouble formulating a title for this one.

The situation is:

```
<body>
    <div id="B">
        <div id="A"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="C"></div>
</body>
```

B is a full-screen div and C is an absolutely positioned footer element, always displayed over all other elements, including B.

A is a popup inside B, and the position of this popup changes so sometimes it can overlap the footer. The thing is, I need this popup to be displayed over the footer while its parent div remains under the footer. Is this possible? Simply changing A's z-index does nothing.

Current CSS:

```
#B{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
}

#A{
    position:absolute;
}

#C{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:300px;
    height:60px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    z-index:5;
}
```

I realize I could take A out of B and place it in the body directly but this would mean rewriting some Javascript, and also I'm just curious if the type of overlapping described above is possible.

Comment: Recommended read: [Philipp Walton - What No One Told You About Z-Index](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> z-index conundrum - if A is child of B and C is displayed over B, can A be displayed over C?

If B establishes a stacking context for A, then no, because A is isolated in B's stacking context and cannot overlap boxes outside that stacking context (unless the stacking context itself overlaps those boxes, which means B would have to overlap C).

So what you're trying to do is not possible without either moving A out of B, or preventing B from establishing a stacking context (it's unclear what purpose the `z-index: 1` declaration for B is serving in your example, but I assume there's more going on in your actual layout that makes this option non-trivial).

Comment: B can be dragged and thus its (also absolute) position is set but I left that out to not complicate things unnecessarily. That's why it has a z-index. Ok, I'll have to revise my HTML structure a bit I suppose.

Comment: @jovan: Yeah, I've been in similar situations. You get used to it after some time.